# My observer not work

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I want to write a observer that take a url and add `?param=1` in the end of urls. I write this code, but it appears to be not working.

```
        ...
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <dk_images_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>DK_Images_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>interceptMethod</method/>
                    </dk_images_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>    
        </events>
    </global>
```

and Observer.php

```
class DK_Images_Model_Observer
{
    public function interceptMethod($observer) 
    {

        $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() . '?param=1';
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue seems to be here:-

```
<method>interceptMethod</method/>
```

change to `<method>interceptMethod</method>`

Comment: Oh, thank's)) Observer is work, but now I get HTTP ERROR 500, how I can change all urls (add ?param=1 in the end) in this observer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove slash `(/)` from method `<method>interceptMethod</method>`

Comment: Oh, thank's)) Observer is work, but now I get HTTP ERROR 500, how I can change all urls (add ?param=1 in the end) in this observer.

Comment: $url = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('param1'=>'val1', '_query'=>array('p1'=>'v1', 'p2'=>'v2')));